# how to login with facebook in Android, iOS and Window Phone using xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, facebook-login, xamarin.forms

**How to login with facebook in android, iOS and Window Phone using xamarin.forms ?**

**If the login is successful then store the credentials.**

My project is xamarin.forms with PCL.

**How can i do implements facebook login integration in my project ?**

thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One of the ways I recommend is https://github.com/adamped/xarch-starter. This is just a starter template but I it shows the Login Pattern I use. This series basically goes through it. http://www.xamarinhelp.com/14-days-to-building-an-enterprise-quality-xamarin-forms-app/

I wrote the code and blog series so just a self promotion disclaimer here, I thought it was relevant to the question.

You can store settings from your PCL using plugins such as

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/1.5.2

You can see the examples from that project.

Remember to only store the token received and not to store any actual credentials on the mobile device.

**Update**

Apologies, I missed the Facebook part. You can use a NuGet package such as http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth

The above info still stands though.